# Given $\|f_n − f_m\|_{\infty,K} < \epsilon$, $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly and $f$ is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f_n$ be analytic on $\Omega$ and suppose that for any $\epsilon > 0$ and compact $K\subseteq \Omega$ there exists $N = N(K,ε)$ where $n,m > N$ implies that $\|f_n − f_m\|_{\infty,K} < \epsilon$.
Then there exists $f$ analytic on $\Omega$ where $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on each compact $K\subseteq\Omega$.

So since $f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, $f_n$ converges to $f$. But how do I show that it is uniformly convergent and further that $f$ is analytic on $\Omega?$

Comment: Is it really true?

Comment: @AndréPorto I’m not sure, I’m trying to see if I can use Morera’s theorem.